# Obtaining String in the format of DD-MON-YY from date

Tags: java, date, formatting, gregorian-calendar

I have the following code generating a random date, but I don't know how to display it in the form of `DD-MON-YY` (for example `12-NOV-12`), which happens to be the SQL standard format for dates (i.e. in the end I plan on passing this data with JDBC into an oracle database).

```
GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();

gc.set(gc.YEAR,  randBetween(1900, 2015)); //randBetween creates a random number between the two

gc.set(gc.DAY_OF_YEAR, randBetween(1, gc.getActualMaximum(gc.DAY_OF_YEAR)));

//Mysterious formatting needed here

String s = //date would go here in the DD-MON-YY format
```

Anyway, point being I have tried many ways to format it and the closest I've got it to has been `DD-MM-YY` (for example `12-12-12`). I was wondering if anyone knew of a short/easy way to achieve my goal without resorting to the primitive long way (if/switch-case statements).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
String s = sdf.format(gc.getTime());
System.out.println(s);
```

This is the part in the javadoc you were looking for:

```
Letter    Date or Time Component             Presentation      Examples
  M       Month in year (context sensitive)      Month      July; Jul; 07
```

> **Month**: If the number of pattern letters is 3 or more, the month is interpreted as text; otherwise, it is interpreted as a number.
>
> - Letter M produces context-sensitive month names, such as the embedded form of names. If a `DateFormatSymbols` has been set explicitly with constructor `SimpleDateFormat(String, DateFormatSymbols)` or method `setDateFormatSymbols(DateFormatSymbols)`, the month names given by the `DateFormatSymbols` are used.
> - Letter L produces the standalone form of month names.

Comment: thanks, I didn't realize uppercase formatting had a different effect :D

Comment: Oh wait, that still displays the number of the month, instead of the three-letter format I was looking for.

Unless that kind of format can be used for the `DATE` type in SQL without using `TO_DATE()` (and I didn't know it), that brings me back to square 1 :/

Comment: @Yokhen you can always read the javadoc posted in the link (it's not for decoration purposes). Fixed the post

Comment: I read the javadoc of several date-like data types, but I failed to see information on formatting. Maybe I just suck at reading. Sorry for asking obvious questions :( EDIT: information on the specific formatting I was looking for. I saw a whole other formats though.

Comment: @Yokhen don't be sorry. Anyway, that should return the expected output.